# Array.Copy() does not work on DataRow in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I've got two arrays, and I need to put the second forward items to the other array using Array.Copy, but nothing happens, it just does not add anything.

Here's the code:

```
DataRow[] auxRows = rFComDataSet.TestStepNames
                   .Select("ScenarioName = '" + scenarioName + "'");

DataRow[] newRows = new DataRow[auxRows.Count()];
auxRows.CopyTo(newRows, 0);           
foreach (DataRow row in newRows)
{
    DataRow teste = this.rFComDataSet.TestStepNames.NewRow();
    Array.Copy(row.ItemArray, 1, teste.ItemArray, 0, 4);
    row["ScenarioName"] = newScenarioName;
    this.rFComDataSet.TestStepNames.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but the copyTo is working, what is not workking is the Array.Copy(row.ItemArray, 1, teste.ItemArray, 0, 4).

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is the consequence of the implementation of the ItemArray property.
This is the code of the GET accessor

```
public object[] ItemArray
{
    get
    {
        int num;
        object[] objArray;
        DataColumn column;
        int num2;
        num2 = this.GetDefaultRecord();
        objArray = new object[this._columns.Count];
        num = 0;
        goto Label_0037;
    Label_001C:
        column = this._columns[num];
        objArray[num] = column[num2];
        num += 1;
    Label_0037:
        if (num < ((int) objArray.Length))
        {
            goto Label_001C;
        }
        return objArray;
    }
}
```

As you can see calling DataRow.ItemArray returns a new object array where the values from the underlyng row are copied to. 
When you use `Array.Copy` you are setting values in this array not in 
the underlying values of the DataRow. So your row remains with the null values

A possible workaround is the following (NOT TESTED)

```
object[] itemArray = new object[this.rFComDataSet.TestStepNames.Columns.Count];
Array.Copy(row.ItemArray, 1, itemArray, 0, 4);
this.rFComDataSet.TestStepNames.Rows.Add(itemArray);
```

In this way we force the underlying values of new row created by Rows.Add to be the value of the object array created separately

There are a couple of things to take note however. Your call `auxRows.CopyTo(newRows, 0);` doesn't create a new row, it just copy all the rows reference to the new array, but they points at the same data, so changing anything in newRows change the corresponding row in auxRows.

Finally it is not clear why you have all this work to copy the row and then add to the TestStepNames table the same row from the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Just skip Copy and do like:

```
DataRow teste = this.rFComDataSet.TestStepNames.NewRow();
teste.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
```

`row.ItemArray` will create a new object for you.